# How to make shell to execute command file without making a new process?

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

Please describe how to do it for sh and csh.

Comment: Does "command file" mean a script file? Or a binary program image file?

Comment: Con you give a bit more info about what you are trying to do. The question is very abstract.

Comment: @JdeBP "Command file" means a script file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `exec` command will *replace* the current shell by the given external utility.  This works both in POSIX shells and in `csh`.

Example: Replace the current shell with an interactive `ksh` shell:

```
$ exec ksh
```

The external utility may also be a script.